# How can I set the background color to the Popupmenu?

Tags: graphics, color, gui-construction

I want to set the `Background` color of a `PopupMenu` to blue. I already searched in the documentation center, but I didn't find any option that seemed suitable.

```
 PopupMenu[
    Dynamic[x], 
    {"Country1", "Country2", "Country3"}, 
    ImageSize -> {180, 60}, Background -> Blue,
    Alignment -> {Center, Center},
    MenuStyle ->Directive[Orange, 20, Bold]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One can get close by using the

```
{value1 -> label1, value2 -> label2, …}
```

format for `PopupMenu` and making the labels with a blue background.

```
countryList = {"Country1", "Country2", "Country3"}

labelList = Map[
  Row[{
     Spacer[{60, 56, 23}],
     Style[#, Orange, 20, Bold, Background -> Blue],
     Spacer[60]
     },
    Background -> Blue] &,
  countryList]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now generate a set of rules to be used as the input to `PopupMenu`

```
popupRules = Map[countryList[[#]] -> labelList[[#]] &, Range[3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now use the rules as input to `PopupMenu`

```
PopupMenu[Dynamic[x],
 popupRules,
 "Country 1",
 ImageSize -> {180, 60},
 Background -> Blue,
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}
 ]
```

[image: PopupMenu]

Answer (score 2):

To get the look subbu asked for on OS X, I had to override the default appearance of the pop-up menu widget. Here is what I came up with:

```
PopupMenu[Dynamic@x, {"Country1", "Country2", "Country3"}, "", 
   Row[{Panel[Style[Dynamic@x, Orange, 20, Bold, Background -> Blue], 
           ImageSize -> {160, 60}, Appearance -> None, Background -> Blue, 
           Alignment -> {Center, Center}], 
        Panel[Style["\[FilledDownTriangle]", 16, Bold, 
           Background -> White], ImageSize -> {20, 60}, Appearance -> None, 
           Alignment -> {Center, Center}]}, Frame -> True, 
      FrameMargins -> None], MenuStyle -> Directive[Orange, 20, Bold]]
```

It produces a control that looks like this:

[image: custom pop-up menu]

Comment: @m_goldberg.Really I like your code.but How can i set background color for Menu ?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you made the blue background in a graphics program to show us what you want because on my computer your blue background is obscured by the default appearance.

[image]

Setting `Appearance->None` will fix this ...although on my mac I lose the "guiding up-down arrows" when I do that.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but could the OP have meant to ask how to color the pop-up part of the menu blue and not the fixed part? The latter he already colored blue.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I assumed he made that in a graphics program because his code does not deliver that screen grab on my computer ...will add a grab.

Comment: It looked like that on my Win7 PC. So, no manual coloring there...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries interesting. Maybe that is what he meant. I'll wait for him to reply/clarify. Might be worth leaving this answer here for Mac users.

Comment: Why no copyable code?

Comment: @ Mike Honeychurch,I want to set background(Blue/anycolor) color to drop down menu of the `PopupMenu`.

Comment: @Mr.wizard the addition involves one option setting which is copyable.